# Submit post echo but does not write information in database

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

I'm having problem with updating information in database. The echo pops out as successful but the database row stays blank - why? PHP code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
        // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
        $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $gender);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  members gender VALUE ?")) {
                $insert_stmt->bind_param('s', $gender);
            }
        }
        echo "<div class='notemarg'> Your gender has been submitted</div>";
    } 
?>
```

and input form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female <br>
  <input type="submit" name="gender" value="Set gender" class="button">
</form>
```

I want to use `mysqli->prepare` to prevent SQL injection.

I fixed it with alternative way, where there is pre-defined input by button.

```
<?php

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
     if (isset($_POST['Female'])) {

     $gender = $_POST['Female'];
     $sql = "UPDATE members SET gender = '$gender' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"; 


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<div class='notemarg'> Your gender has been submitted</div>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
    ?>
```

And simple form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="submit" name="Female" value="Female" class="button">
</form>
```

Thanks to all who wanted to help me, especially to anant kumar singh. I could not get that alter idea without his suggestions. Thanks!

**UPDATE #1**

It just pops out that echo "error"

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Female'])){

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
     if (isset($_POST['Female'])) {

     $gender = $_POST['Female'];
     $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE members
     SET gender = ?
     WHERE username = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['Female']);
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);

    if ($conn->prepare === TRUE) {
        echo "<font color='#00CC00'>Your gender has been updated.</font><p>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $conn->prepare . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
}
?>
```

Don't know where is problem...
**UPDATE #2**

```
if(isset($_POST['Female'])){

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

  // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
     if (isset($_POST['Female'])) {

     $gender = $_POST['Female'];
     $sql = "
     UPDATE members
     SET gender = ?
     WHERE username = ?
 ";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['Female']);
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);
 $stmt->execute();

    if ($mysqli->prepare($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<font color='#00CC00'>Your gender has been updated.</font><p>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $conn->prepare . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
}
```

**UPDATE #3**

I added also some notes in code so

```
     <?php
    // I had here twice the ifisset here and
        if(isset($_POST['Female'])){

        $servername = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";

       // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    //here the second one so I deleted that ifisset here...
         $gender = $_POST['Female'];
         $sql = "
         UPDATE members
         SET gender = ?
         WHERE username = ?
     ";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['Female']);
     $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);
     $ok = $stmt->execute();

        if ($ok == TRUE) {
            echo "<font color='#00CC00'>Your gender has been updated.</font><p>";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " .$stmt->error; // This is the line that shows the error
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

I'm not sure what is problem... It pops the error on echo "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: I want to add "gender" in the database as selected in form

Comment: update or insert ? your code is contradictory to your question .

Comment: Insert. Because the gender is at the start blank row in db..

Comment: "INSERT INTO  members gender VALUES (?)" try this sql query instead interrogation mark shall be wrapped with parentheses

Comment: @яша - Does not work.:/

Comment: @StevenTomko I edited my query try now

Comment: The table is `members` and the column is `gender`?

Comment: Just a guess but shouldn't you execute your query?

Comment: @steven - did.. nothing :/

Comment: <input type="submit" name="gender" value="Set gender" class="button"> -> i would change submit button name, first...

Comment: @nevermind - Why? there is $_POST['name'] so it does not matter

Comment: Hm... value of $_POST['gender'] will always be 'Set gender' - not sure that you need it.

Comment: Your "fixed" version as supplied by the helpful poster below has a SQL injection vulnerability in it - I advise you **not to use it**. Carry on fixing the parameterised approach.

Comment: @halfer so how to avoid the sql injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following an answer being posted with a huge security vulnerability, it is worth taking a moment to fix this. There *is* a way to fix it so you can use your string concatenation approach, but it is generally not as good as parameterisation.

All you need to do is to take your working query, and convert it to a parameterised form. Something like this:

```
 // Expects valid $mysqli object here
 $sql = "
     UPDATE members
     SET gender = ?
     WHERE username = ?
 ";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

 // ** As we discovered, the binding needs to happen in one
 // ** call, not across several
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['Female'], $_SESSION['username']);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Looking at your original code, there seems to have been two problems: the statement wasn't prepared at all (and so the program should have exited with a fatal error) and there was a syntax error in the original SQL statement.

In your new code, you're missing the `execute()` call.

Comment: I got an **Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object**

Comment: I've just fixed a typo, maybe that was it? Don't forget to check the MySQLi manual too, there may be something for `bind_param()` I've missed (I don't know much about it, I prefer PDO).

Comment: Err... you have created the `$stmt` object with `prepare()`, right, as per your original code sample?

Comment: I think that I'll install PDO instead :D

Comment: No no no @Steven, carry on as you are with MySQLi. If you always give up with such small problems, you'll soon run out of libraries. I suspect you are just missing the `prepare()` line - and indeed this looks like the problem you were having to start with. Try adding it?

Comment: I'm trying so hard but i can't figure it out... could you include some more instructions? cause I just got an Error on echo... and the database didnt change on submit...could you try to rewrite my code? so I can compare them what is wrong...check update#1

Comment: I won't rewrite your code @Steven - that's not helpful to the learning experience - but I will get you started. See my edit for notes on the problems in your original code, and in your new code.

Comment: It now seems you're trying to `prepare()` it twice. Use `$ok =  $stmt->execute()` instead, and check the value of `$ok`.

Comment: I assume you mean "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object". OK, that sounds like your preparation has failed - does `$stmt->error` come back with anything?

Comment: No no.. I mean .. that I get that "error" on ECHO... so it looks like there is something unsuccessful because it pops the **else { echo...** Not a call to a member function ...

Comment: OK @Steven. Now try `echo "Error: " .$stmt->error;` instead of that line - does that output any specific error? I've swapped the connection variable to the statement variable instead.

Comment: Yes... I got an error : **No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement** What does that mean? o.O

Comment: Last attempt from me @Steven, since I don't know this API. Take a look at the [manual page for the bind method](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) - it makes it seem that you can do binding all in one go. Maybe it's the only way? Thus, try `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['Female'], $_SESSION['username'])` instead of the two calls you have now.

Comment: -It works now!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks :O Selecting your answer (y) Good job and thanks!